# how to restrict some specific characters in javascript regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using a regular expression to validate an email address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address)

I have just made a RE for email address. Its a simplest one and works well. But i want to make it more better. I mean to say that, an email address can have alphanumeric characters, underscores "_", dot "." but it cannot contain hyphen "-", semicolon ";" etc. Below is my RE that i have just made for email address.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<script>
str = "assad-ch7@Yahoo.com";

re = /[a-z0-9][@]((yahoo)|(hotmail)|(gmail))[.]((com)|(co.uk))/i; 


result = re.test(str);

document.write(result);

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Furthermore, is this the right way to make an RE for an email address??

Comment: You may want to add `^` and `$` to your regex ;) Also, `.` needs to be escaped if you want to match a literal dot: `co\.uk`. Further, you will want a quantifier : `[a-z0-9]+`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not bad if you want to limit the email addresses to those domains. There are a few fixes though

1. Need _ and . in first character class
2. Add + after first character class to capture all characters before @
3. Remove @ and . from character class brackets
4. Remove unnecessary extra parenthesis
5. Backslash literal periods (unnecessary inside character classes)

`var re = /[a-z0-9_.]+@(yahoo|hotmail|gmail)\.(com|co\.uk)/i;`

Comment: Thank you so much @Brian Cray. Its really informative for me. Can you please suggest me a website where i can get RE tutorials.

Comment: Sure, I learned long time ago using http://www.regular-expressions.info

Comment: So nice of you @Brian Cray. Thank you so much.